# Flex Slider (v2) moving itself out of container div

Tags: drupal, flexslider

In Drupal im using views to generate a normal UL list inside  a container div.

Then flexslider is activated and takes the ul list out the container div and creates a new div container named "flex-viewport" as a sibling to my original container div, putting the UL there now.

I'm totally clueless why or how, any ideas? I can only assume its something in the Flexslider.js

Answer (score 0):

This was a case of the jQuery select being flexslider, not the container div. so `$('.flexslider').flexslider()` should be `$('.view-content').flexslider()`

note: consider hierarchy to prevent flex slider picking up all view-content divs `$('.flexsliderwrap .view-content').flexslider()`